# How do I open a web browser (URL) from my Flutter code?

Tags: flutter, dart, url, browser, webbrowser-control

I am building a Flutter app, and I'd like to open a URL into a web browser or browser window (in response to a button tap). How can I do this?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chinmaygarde/d778498418e30825d687147b79d070eb This may help.

Comment: After some search, this issue can be solved via instructions listed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-dev/J3ujgdOuG98 The above `UrlLauncher` is no longer usable.

Answer (score 334, accepted):

**TL;DR**

This is now implemented as [Plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher)

```
 final Uri url = Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev');
 if (!await launchUrl(url)) {
      throw Exception('Could not launch $_url');
 }
```

---

Full example:

> ```
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
>
> void main() {
>   runApp(new Scaffold(
>     body: new Center(
>       child: new RaisedButton(
>         onPressed: _launchURL,
>         child: new Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
>       ),
>     ),
>   ));
> }
>
> _launchURL() async {
>    final Uri url = Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev');
>    if (!await launchUrl(url)) {
>         throw Exception('Could not launch $_url');
>     }
> }
> ```

In pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  url_launcher: ^6.1.11
```

Check out the latest [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package.

#### Special Characters:

If the `url` value contains spaces or other values that are now allowed in URLs, use

`Uri.encodeFull(urlString)` or `Uri.encodeComponent(urlString)` and pass the resulting value instead.

Comment: Note that you might need to either create a new flutter project and copy over your Flutter specific stuff (`lib`, `pubspec.yaml`, etc.) or conversely update the platform specific folders in your old project for this to work.

Comment: Note: Don't forget to add `url_launcher: ^3.0.2` to the pubspec.yaml

Comment: What do you mean with "added to existing apps"? Perhaps your files in `android/` or `ios/` are outdated. If it works in a new app then compare the files and update them in your project. You can also delete these directories and run `flutter create .` and then re-apply manual changes.

Comment: @hbhakhra Now [url_launcher: ^5.0.2](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher#-installing-tab-) Keep checking.

Comment: How to open link for flutter_web where url_launcher plug-in is not available ?

Comment: Why would it not be available? You can write the code yourself. The urllauncher plugin is open source and you can check out its source and learn what it does. You can do the same in your applications code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, may I ask you to have a look at a Flutter related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565658/fluter-image-picker-package-show-images-one-after-another-with-delete-action ?

Comment: If you get Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException just **stop** the app and then run it again

Comment: This works fine, the problem is that when I try to open a Facebook Messenger url, it is redirecting to `intent://` and fails with `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

Comment: Only Android knows about that scheme. You'd need to call into Android (create a plugin in Java) to resolve the URL there and load the content from it, and then pass it back to Flutter. That's not a simple task. What exactly is the original URL for?

Comment: is it possible to open Chrome in desktop mode in mobile?

Comment: Great solution~ Just updating it a bit since launch and canLaunch are now deprecated.

Future<bool> launchURL(url) async {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
    await launchUrl(url);
    print("launched URL: $url");
    return true;
  } else {
    print('Could not launch $url');
    return false;
  }
}

Comment: url_launcher does not open if https has cert issues. doesnt look like an alternative is available.

Comment: This solution is not true. launchUrl does not open the link in an external browser like Chrome or Firefox, it just open the link in the Android basic web browser. You need to add ` mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication`

Comment: thx, this is really works for me. The _launchUrl method can be assigned as void too.

Answer (score 78):

If you target sdk 30 or above `canLaunch` will return false by default due to package visibility changes: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility

in the `androidManifest.xml` you'll need to add the following directly under `<manifest>`:

```xml
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Then the following should word - for flutter 3 upwards:

```dart
const uri = Uri.parse("https://flutter.io");
if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)){
    await launchUrl(uri);
} else {
    // can't launch url
}
```

or for older versions of flutter use this instead:

```dart
const url = "https://flutter.io";
if (await canLaunch(url)){
    await launch(url);
} else {
    // can't launch url
}
```

`launchUrl` has a `mode` parameter which can be used to control where the url gets launched.

So, passing in `launchUrl(uri, mode: LaunchMode.platformDefault)` leaves the decision of how to launch the URL to the platform
implementation. But you can also specify

`LaunchMode.inAppWebView` which will use an in-app web view
`LaunchMode.externalApplication` for it to be handled by an external application

Or `LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication` to be handled by a non-browser application.

Comment: Can you describe exactly where to place the <queries> portion in XML file?

Comment: It should be directly under <manifest> so at the same level as things like <uses-permissions> and <application>

Comment: This method is deprecated now. It tells me to use ```launchUrl``` instead of ```launch```. However, ```launchUrl``` opens a webview inside my app. This is not what I want. Got any tips?

Comment: @Anteino I've updated the answer to use the non-deprecated url and added details on where the url will launch with `mode`

Comment: Suppose we want to connect to Facebook, how can we be directed to FB app , if it is installed, else browser ?

Comment: This `AndroidManifest.xml` step is not needed for this question, which is about actually opening a URL. It's only needed for `canLaunchUrl` (and the deprecated `canLaunch`).

Comment: @Anteino, to open on the extranal browser use : `launchUrl(Uri.parse(url), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication))`

Answer (score 18):

**The best way is to use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package .**

Add **url_launcher** as a dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
dependencies:
  url_launcher:
```

**An example of how to use it :**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flutter is beautiful'),),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _launchURL,
          child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
        ),
      ),
    )),
  );
}

_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.dev';
  if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
    await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url));
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

**Output :**
[image]

> The **launch** method takes a string argument containing a URL .
> By default, Android opens up a browser when handling URLs. You can
> pass `forceWebView: true` parameter to tell the plugin to open a **WebView**
> instead. If you do this for a URL of a page containing JavaScript,
> make sure to pass in `enableJavaScript: true`, or else the launch method
> will not work properly. On iOS, the default behavior is to open all
> web URLs within the app. Everything else is redirected to the app
> handler.

Comment: Is it possible to close the app after the URL is launched? I tried it with exit(0) but it also closes the browser.

Comment: @ManoHaran You can use forceSafariVC to open URL in default browser of the phone: await launch(URL, forceSafariVC: false);

Comment: care canLaunch is now deprecated ;)

Answer (score 17):

**For Flutter:**

As described [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43889379/5066615) by Günter Zöchbauer

**For Flutter Web:**

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
```

Then use:

```
html.window.open(url, name);
```

Make sure that you run `flutter clean` if the `import` doesn't resolve.

Comment: The [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package supports web now

Answer (score 14):

For those who wants to implement LAUNCH BROWSER AND EXIT APP by using url_launcher. Remember to use (forceSafariVC: false) to open the url in default browser of the phone. Otherwise, the launched browser exit along with your APP.

```
await launch(URL, forceSafariVC: false);
```

Comment: This is what I need as I have to launch a Firebase Dynamic Link from a QR code scanner that is provided in the app. I need the URL to launch externally so it is then recognised as a dynamic link in the app and handled appropriately.

Answer (score 9):

This is now implemented as [Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWd2w.jpg)

> ```
>     const url = "https://flutter.io";
>     final Uri _url = Uri.parse(url);
>
>     await launchUrl(_url,mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
> ```

```
 pubspec.yaml 
Add dependencies
```

> dependencies:   url_launcher: ^6.0.12

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWd2w.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use url_launcher than please use it in this form

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  url_launcher: ^5.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

This answer is also for absolute beginners: They are thinking behind the flutter sdk. 
No that was a failure. The packages were extras and not in the flutter Sdk. These were secondary packages (single small framework helpers).

Answer (score 2):

The [PLUGIN](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) plugin works great, as you explain in your examples.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
final Uri _url = Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev');
void main() => runApp(
  const MaterialApp(
    home: Material(
      child: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: launchUrlStart(url: "https://flutter.dev"),
          child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

Future<void> launchUrlStart({required String url}) async {
if (!await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
 }
}
```

But when trying to open PDF https://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf it remained blank, the problem was that the browser handled it in its own way. Therefore the solution was to tell it to open with an external application and it worked as expected.

```
Future<void> launchUrlStart({required String url}) async {
  if (!await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url),mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)) {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

In pubspec.yaml

```
#https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher
url_launcher: ^6.1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

using the url_launcher package to do the following:

```
dependencies:
  url_launcher: ^latest_version


if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
    await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url));
}
```

**Note**: Ensure you are trying to open a URI, not a String.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open it in a local browser, the url_launcher package has a feature like this:

```
launchUrlString('https://exemple.com,mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
```