# How do you open the default email app on an iPhone with Flutter?

Tags: ios, email, dart, flutter

I want to make a Flutter app and one of the requirements is to open the native email client on the Android or iPhone device. I do NOT wish to create a new email, just open the email app. I would like to be able to open the email client with platform generic code if possible, if not I would like to know what would be required on the iOS side.  I am not looking for the Send Email Intent, as I know there is a plugin in Flutter for that. Being a Android Developer I believe I know how to call an Intent from Flutter for that Implicit Intent, if I have to go that way, but I don't have the familiarity with iOS.

Answer (score 43):

The [url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) plugin does that

> ```
> mailto:<email address>?subject=<subject>&body=<body>
> ```

> Create email to  in the default email app

See also [How do I open a web browser (URL) from my Flutter code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149055/how-do-i-open-a-web-browser-url-from-my-flutter-code/43889379#43889379)

Comment: I don't want to create a new email, I just want to open the default email app.

Comment: Sorry, don't know about that

Comment: Try `message:` instead of `mailto: ...`

Comment: You probably need to use `Uri.encodeFull('It is not ok')` or `Uri.encodeComponent('It isnot ok')` and pass the resulting value instead.

Comment: @AlejandroIván is that just for iOS?

Answer (score 30):

You need two plugins: `android_intent` and `url_launcher`

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
    action: 'android.intent.action.MAIN',
    category: 'android.intent.category.APP_EMAIL',
  );
  intent.launch().catchError((e) {
    ;
  });
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  launch("message://").catchError((e){
    ;
  });
}
```

Comment: On Android, this will open the email app inside your app. To open it in a new window add: `flags: [Flag.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK]`

Comment: launch("message://") is not working in Simulator

Comment: `android_intent` has been replaced by `android_intent_plus`

Answer (score 12):

use url_launcher plugin [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

```
Future<void> _launched;

Future<void> _openUrl(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
}
```

Then for Phone

```
setState(() {
  _launched = _openUrl('tel:${+917600896744}');
});
```

for email

```
setState(() {
  _launched = _openUrl('mailto:${sejpalbhargav67@gmail.com}'');
});
```

**Update July 2021**

Add Following Lines in Manifest File

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

<queries>
<intent>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent>
<intent>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
  <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent>
<intent>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent>
```

Comment: This will send an email, not what the op wants.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `open_mail_app: ^0.4.5` for this, it works pretty well and it took 2 min to add it to my app:

```
// Android: Will open mail app or show native picker.
// iOS: Will open mail app if single mail app found.
var result = await OpenMailApp.openMailApp();
```

It shows all 3 of my email apps that I have installed on my android smartphone, but for some reason it also gives the option to open my paypal app, which could make users of my app think to be a bit sus.

The developer of open_mail_app has added a filter to filter out paypal, but it seems not to work:

```
/// Default filter list includes PayPal, since it implements the mailto: intent-filter
/// on Android, but the intention of this plugin is to provide
/// a utility for finding and opening apps dedicated to sending/receiving email.
```

Answer (score 3):

U can use [url_luncher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher):

```
await launchUrl(Uri.parse("mailto:email?subject=subject&body=body"))
```

& don't use launch as it's deprecated:

```
launch("mailto:<email address>?subject=<subject>&body=<body>");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
launch("mailto:<email address>?subject=<subject>&body=<body>");
```

use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package

Comment: `launch` is now deprecated. Now, you should use `launchUrl` and it doesn't take a String, it takes a Uri(), and I'm struggling with how to write that Uri correctly!... I've made it open in the browser by using `Uri.https()`, but not in the e-mail app... There is the `Uri(path: 'String_path')` but that String can't contain a colon, so I can't write "mailto:".... Help?

Answer (score 1):

In theory this line of code should resolve the problem

```
String email = 'yourEmail@domain.com';
String title = 'The subject';
String message = '';
await launch(mailto:$email?subject=$title&body=$message);
```

But for some reason the subject and body are ignored, and to solve this issue check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60927693/7360275), it should work smoothly for all required parameters.

the working code:

```
final Uri params = Uri(
  scheme: 'mailto',
  path: email,
  query: 'subject=$title&body=$message',
);

var url = params.toString();
await launch(url);
```

Comment: This is the working soultion! Thanks

Comment: I had to add another dependency to use lunchUrl method, but this answer worked thanks !

Answer (score 1):

use url_launcher plugin url_launcher

```
Future<void> _openUrl(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
}
```

for Phone

```
 _openUrl(Uri.parse('tel:${+917600896744}'));
```

for email

```
_openUrl(Uri.parse('mailto:ah@gmail.com'));
```

for browser

```
_openUrl(Uri.parse('https://google.com'));
```

Update July 2021

Add Following Lines in Manifest File

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

<queries>
<intent>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent>
<intent>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
  <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent>
<intent>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent>
```

Answer (score 0):

this answer may be the solution [How to open default email app inbox in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701038/how-to-open-default-email-app-inbox-in-flutter/55721007)

```
void openEmailApp(BuildContext context){
    try{
        AppAvailability.launchApp(Platform.isIOS ? "message://" : "com.google.android.gm").then((_) {
                print("App Email launched!");
              }).catchError((err) {
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: Text("App Email not found!")
                ));
                print(err);
              });
    } catch(e) {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Email App not found!")));
    }
}
```

Comment: AppAvailability is an outdated plugin, if you use this it will generate when you releasing the build . So please avoid using this plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package to open mail app in a device,https://pub.dev/packages/open_mail_app

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to the above problem that is working now!

```
 sendAnEmail(String email) async {
    const title = "Need support!";
    const message = "";
    final Uri url = Uri(
      scheme: 'mailto',
      path: email,
      query: 'subject=$title&body=$message',
    );

    await launchUrl(url);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [email_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/email_launcher)

Example

```dart
Email email = Email(
    to: ['one@gmail.com,two@gmail.com'],
    cc: ['foo@gmail.com'],
    bcc: ['bar@gmail.com'],
    subject: 'subject',
    body: 'body'
);
await EmailLauncher.launch(email);
```

Answer (score -1):

This library solved it perfectly for me: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender. The example is good and the api is simple and obvious.

Comment: The op clearly said he doesn't want to send an email.

Comment: The library allows you to open the email app without sending the email.

Comment: @zkon , I'd recommend you edit your answer to include exactly how to open the email app without sending the email! Otherwise, your answer will get downvoted, because ppl believe (from reading the package documentation) that the package can only send emails. Reading the documentation also takes a lot more time than if you would just write the relevant code here! So that would be very helpful, since you apparently know it.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a similar solution and I found this package [**Open_mail_app**](https://pub.dev/packages/open_mail_app). You can read through the readme.md on how to use it in your app.

[I will update this answer soon]