# How to open default email app inbox in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to open the default e-mail app Inbox screen using flutter. We can use url launcher to open the email compose screen with mailto: url. But that opens the compose screen. What I want is to open the inbox screen. I can't find proper documentation for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you open the default email app on an iPhone with Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091785/how-do-you-open-the-default-email-app-on-an-iphone-with-flutter)

Comment: @kkarakk That solution did not work for me.

Comment: what happens when you try and use it?

Comment: @kkarakk It opens the mail compose screen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer using [flutter_appavailability](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_appavailability) library.
For those who are searching for the answer please see the steps below.

1. Add dependency | flutter_appavailability: "^0.0.21" | in pubspec.yaml (Please check the latest version in [GitHub](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_appavailability))
2. Add below lines in Xcode Podfile which is required for building the library in iOS

```
    target 'Runner' do
      use_frameworks!  # required by simple_permission
      ...
    end
    
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'  # required by simple_permission
          config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
```

3. Import below packages

   import 'dart:io';
   import 'package:flutter_appavailability/flutter_appavailability.dart';
4. Use below method

   ```
    void openEmailApp(BuildContext context){
        try{
            AppAvailability.launchApp(Platform.isIOS ? "message://" : "com.google.android.gm").then((_) {
                    print("App Email launched!");
                  }).catchError((err) {
                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        content: Text("App Email not found!")
                    ));
                    print(err);
                  });
        } catch(e) {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Email App not found!")));
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I've lost some days already but you stopped the meaningless trying. How can I make this post exposure to google well?

Comment: The package seem abandoned... no effort to migrate to null safety.

Comment: AppAvailability is an outdated plugin, if you use this it will generate when you releasing the build . So please avoid using this plugin

Answer (score -2):

Updated answer: Use https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher and once imported you can create a  function

```
_sendingMails() async {
      const url = 'mailto:feedback@geeksforgeeks.org';
      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(url);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    }
```

I followed this tutorial here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mail-and-sms-in-flutter/

Comment: For anyone using iOS simulator, you'll have to use a physical device to test since it doesn't work on the simulator.