# how to redirect a flutter app to zoom meetings app?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to redirect a flutter app to do any function in zoom meetings, like making a call or something similar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can any one tell me how to open another app using flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55771211/can-any-one-tell-me-how-to-open-another-app-using-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

By Using flutter_zoom_plugin: ^0.0.8 you can do it.

Note:- First of all you have to create your account on Zoom official website where You can create app key and secret key.

Code:-

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:astro_school/Widgets/toastMessages.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_zoom_sdk/zoom_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter_zoom_sdk/zoom_options.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class JoinClass extends StatelessWidget {
  
  late ZoomOptions zoomOptions;
  late ZoomMeetingOptions meetingOptions;

  late Timer timer;

  JoinClass({Key? key, meetingId, meetingPassword,username}) : super(key: key) {
    
    this.zoomOptions = new ZoomOptions(
      domain: "zoom.us",//here should be domain
      appKey: "rRSxNxnhGnXHHLKGGm60TcKVOWzRAKJulvrP",//app key
      appSecret: "FuX7v05IcyCLcLwu6pRxRl0bNHbii4LNdn4z",//secret key
    );
    this.meetingOptions = new ZoomMeetingOptions(
        userId: username, //pass username for join meeting only
        meetingId: meetingId, //pass meeting id for join meeting only
        meetingPassword: meetingPassword, //pass meeting password for join meeting only
        disableDialIn: "true",
        disableDrive: "true",
        disableInvite: "true",
        disableShare: "true",
        disableTitlebar: "false",
        viewOptions: "true",
        noAudio: "false",
        noDisconnectAudio: "false"
    );
  }

  bool _isMeetingEnded(String status) {
    var result = false;

    if (Platform.isAndroid)
      result = status == "MEETING_STATUS_DISCONNECTING" || status == "MEETING_STATUS_FAILED";
    else
      result = status == "MEETING_STATUS_IDLE";

    return result;
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Use the Todo to create the UI.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor:Color(0xff5D1445),
          title: Text('Loading meeting '),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: ZoomView(onViewCreated: (controller) {

          print("Created the view");

          controller.initZoom(this.zoomOptions)
              .then((results) {

            print("initialised");
            print(results);

            if(results[0] == 0) {

              controller.zoomStatusEvents.listen((status) {
            //    print("Meeting Status Stream: " + status[0] + " - " + status[1]);
                if (_isMeetingEnded(status[0])) {
                
                   timer.cancel();
                   Get.toNamed('/home',);
                 
                }
              });

              print("listen on event channel");

              controller.joinMeeting(this.meetingOptions)
                  .then((joinMeetingResult) {

                timer = Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
                  controller.meetingStatus(this.meetingOptions.meetingId!)
                      .then((status) {
                      //  message('sdfdfd');
                    print("Meeting Status Polling: " + status[0] + " - " + status[1]);
                  });
                });

              });
            }

          }).catchError((error) {
message(error);
         //   print("Error");
            print(error);
          });
        })
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).