# how to launch an app on your mobile phone from a flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

in native Android, we can launch another app like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(url)));
```

how can this be accomplished in Flutter/dart?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can any one tell me how to open another app using flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55771211/can-any-one-tell-me-how-to-open-another-app-using-flutter)

Comment: You can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appavailability package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Share_Plus plugin and archive your goal.
import this package in your pubspacs.yaml file

```
share_plus: ^3.0.4
```

then import it using `import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';`

Now you can use

```
Share.share('Sharing Text', subject: 'Sharing Subjects');
```

You can also share file using

```
Share.shareFiles(['${directory.path}/image.jpg'], text: 'Great picture');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [External app launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/external_app_launcher) package you can run the app you want using the package name using the following

import the package then

```
import 'package:external_app_launcher/external_app_launcher.dart';
```

use this to launch the app if it is installed else it will send to play store

```
await LaunchApp.openApp(
        androidPackageName: 'com.whatsapp',
        openStore: true);
```