# How can I open/redirect my flutter app to open the default recorder app on the phone?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any plugin to trigger this? I want to open the recorder app when I press a button! Thanks.

Comment: there is no default recorder app. Different brands of phones have different apps for it, or might not even have one at all

Comment: I'm only trying to run it on a Pixel 4a. This is for my university project.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:external_app_launcher/external_app_launcher.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
 _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
}

Color containerColor = Colors.red;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        width: 150,
        child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () async {
              await LaunchApp.openApp(
                androidPackageName: 'net.pulsesecure.   pulsesecure',
                iosUrlScheme: 'pulsesecure://',
                appStoreLink:
                    'itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/   app/pulse- 
 secure/id945832041',
                // openStore: false
              );
              // Enter thr package name of the App you  want to open and 
for iOS add the     URLscheme to the Info.plist file.
              // The second arguments decide wether the     app 
redirects PlayStore or AppStore.
              // For testing purpose you can enter com. 
instagram.android
            },
            child: Container(
                child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Open",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ))),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
 }
}
```

**For more information, check out this answer: [How to open another app using flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55771211/can-any-one-tell-me-how-to-open-another-app-using-flutter)**
**Youtube Tutorial:**[Flutter Tutorial - Open Apps, Launch Urls in Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ET4HfMH-AoQ)