# How to open whatsapp app from my flutter-android app

Tags: android, flutter

I have been trying to open the whatsapp aplication from my flutter app. But it trying to opening the whatssap in my same app, instead of open the whatsapp app. And also, once it open, inmediately show my an error message.
Y have tried all the possible combination that could be in internet.

```
 void _showWhatssap() async {

String whatsapp = '+593963631704';   

var whatsappURlAndroid = Uri.parse('https://wa.me/$whatsapp');    
    
var whatappURLIos =
    Uri.parse('https://wa.me/$whatsapp?text=${Uri.parse("hello")}');

if (Platform.isIOS) {
  // for iOS phone only
  if (await canLaunchUrl(whatappURLIos)) {
    await launchUrl(whatappURLIos);
  } else {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: new Text("whatsapp no installed")));
  }
}
else {
  bool status  = await canLaunchUrl(whatsappURlAndroid);
  print("ESTADO: ${status}");
  if (status) {

    await launchUrl(whatsappURlAndroid);
  } else {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: new Text("whatsapp no installed para android")));
  }
}
```

}
}

[image]

Comment: Did you take a look at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55771211/can-any-one-tell-me-how-to-open-another-app-using-flutter)?

Answer (score 0):

using url luncher
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher
make sure u Follow the Instructions cuze it's work fine with me

```
void _showWhatssap() async {

var whatsappUrl ="whatsapp://send?phone=+593963631704&text=hi";
await canLaunch(whatsappUrl)? launch(whatsappUrl):print("open whatsapp app link or do a snackbar with notification that there is no whatsapp installed");

}
```

and u can see this
https://pub.dev/packages/whatsapp_share2

and u can check this
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launch
it's for whatsapp example

Comment: canLaunch and launch is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following package to check app availability and open it.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appavailability

Comment: This package is not support Null Safety.