# Problem to send email with URL launcher in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello I try to launch email page with recipent. I tried flutter email sender who work with android but not on ios for me. So I tried url launcher to do the same thing, but not working also with iOS. I use iOS simulator, the problem can be this ?

I use this example of url launcher

```
mailto:xxxxx@xxxxx.com?subject=News&body=New%20plugin
```

I have this error

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Could not launch mailto:xxxx@xxxx.com?subject=News&body=New%20plugin
#0      _menuscreenState._launchURL (package:xxxx/bottom.dart:8285:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _menuscreenState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:xxxx/bottom.dart:8705:13)
```

Here is the full example with url launcher

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {


  String email="contact@ouiquit.com";
  _launchEmail() async {
    if (await canLaunch("mailto:$email")) {
      await launch("mailto:$email");
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.red),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('test mail'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              onPressed: _launchEmail,
              icon: Icon(Icons.send),
            )
          ],
        ),


      ),
    );
  }


}
```

Here is the error

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method canLaunch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)
#0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:314:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      canLaunch (package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart:112:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _MyAppState._launchEmail (package:testmail/main.dart:20:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:654:14)
#4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:729:32)
#5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:365:11)
#7      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:275:7)
#8      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/<…>
```

Answer (score 41):

This works for me on both Android and iOS devices:

Add `query` parameter if you have `subject` and `body` too.

```
final Uri params = Uri(
  scheme: 'mailto',
  path: 'email@example.com',
  query: 'subject=App Feedback&body=App Version 3.23', //add subject and body here
);

var url = params.toString();
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

For Android `API >= 30`, do not forget to add these in your `AndroidManifest.xml`,

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Working Thanks!

Comment: How to attach image in mail body from flutter code

Comment: To note that <queries> element should be added as a child of the <manifest> element, before the <application> element.

Answer (score 28):

The above given solutions will work for `API < 30` but for `API >= 30` the following is needed to be added to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for email sending to work.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

[source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63727)

Comment: I'm só glad you are not stuck in your PhD anymore so you can share such a very helpful answer. THANK you!

Comment: Haha.. Thank you <3

Comment: To note that <queries> element should be added as a child of the <manifest> element, before the <application> element.

Answer (score 11):

For iOS

There is no Email App installed on the iOS Simulator you only can test this on a real device.

Answer (score 4):

This is the function I use to send mail using url_launcher :

```
void _launchURL() async {
    final Uri params = Uri(
      scheme: 'mailto',
      path: 'my.mail@example.com',
    );
    String  url = params.toString();
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      print( 'Could not launch $url');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

For all people still wondering why it is not working like I did. Remember that the simulator cannot handle mailto because the mail application is not available. If you use canLaunch before calling launch you will get more info.

Answer (score 2):

try mailto plugin

https://pub.dev/packages/mailto#-readme-tab-

it works in both android & ios on device, it works great..

```
void funcOpenMailComposer() async{

    final mailtoLink = Mailto(
      to: ['test@gmail.com'],
      cc: ['test12@gmail.com','test13@gmail.com'],
      subject: '',
      body: '',
    );
  await launch('$mailtoLink');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I added this line in my manifest and I was able to start a call, open maps etc.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

[more info](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779?hl=en)

Comment: Be aware if you do that, you will have to declare the usage of this permission on Google Play when deploying a production release.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, I have used this and it's working fine for me.

```
 _launchEmail() async {
      if (await canLaunch("mailto:$email")) {
        await launch("mailto:$email");
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch';
      }
    }
```

Comment: I upgrade the post with full example with your code and it's not working

Comment: I have the answe, there is no possibility to call mail app on the iOS emulator

Comment: what about on android emulator? I get a crash on android on app startup, emulator and device.

Comment: Please Open the Bug issue in url_launcher gitHub. But it is working with Phones.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS i have add like this

**

```
_launchEmail() async {
    // ios specification
    final String subject = "Subject:";
    final String stringText = "Same Message:";
    String uri = 'mailto:administrator@gmail.com?subject=${Uri.encodeComponent(subject)}&body=${Uri.encodeComponent(stringText)}';
    if (await canLaunch(uri)) {
      await launch(uri);
    } else {
      print("No email client found");
    }
  }
```

**

Comment: what about the Info.plist? did you add any key on it?

Comment: Please add the :    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>sms</string>
  <string>tel</string> <string>mailto</string>
</array>

Comment: are you able to trigger email client opening in the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

There might be an issue with testing email functionality using the URL launcher on the iOS Simulator. The simulator does not come with a default Mail app, so you won't be able to send emails directly from it. To test email functionality, it's recommended to run your Flutter app on a real iOS device where an email client is available. This limitation is specific to the simulator environment and does not affect the functionality on actual devices