# how to make flutter hyperlink?

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

how do I create an email hyperlin in flutter?
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
  AlertDialog alert = const AlertDialog(
    title: Text('Contact us'),
    content: Text(
        'Please contact our team via email: **myemail@email.com**', //hyperlink
    ),
  );
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context){
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you open the default email app on an iPhone with Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091785/how-do-you-open-the-default-email-app-on-an-iphone-with-flutter)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but in my case the hyperlink is in a text inside AlertDialog, I really don't know how to do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri emailLanuch = Uri(
    scheme: 'mailto',
    path: "myemail@email.com",
  );
  showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {

    AlertDialog alert =AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Contact us'),
      content: ,
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await launch(emailLanuch.toString());
          },
          child: Text("myemail@email.com"),
        ),
      ],
    );
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Flutter natively support Rich text, but I think doesn't enough for you. You can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) for your operations, and you can handle your link directly.(If you want you should be to write custom action for links for instance below code)

```
Widget html = Html(
  data: """<p>
   Linking to <a href='https://github.com'>websites</a> has never been easier.
  </p>""",
  onLinkTap: (String? url, RenderContext context, Map<String, String> attributes, dom.Element? element) {
    //open URL in webview, or launch URL in browser, or any other logic here
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Package [url_launcher:](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

```
 final Uri emailLaunchUri = Uri(
  scheme: 'StackOverFlow',
  path: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
  query: encodeQueryParameters(<String, String>{
    'subject': 'Example Subject & Symbols are allowed!'
  }),
);

launch(emailLaunchUri.toString());
```

Comment: Could you show me how to use url_launcher in my code? because I couldn't insert the hyperlink only in the email.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can use this package to send email directly

[email_launcher: ^1.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/email_launcher/install)

```
  import 'package:email_launcher/email_launcher.dart';


Email email = Email(
    to: ['one@gmail.com,two@gmail.com'],
    cc: ['foo@gmail.com'],
    bcc: ['bar@gmail.com'],
    subject: 'subject',
    body: 'body'
);
await EmailLauncher.launch(email);
```

Comment: Could you show me how to use email_launcher in my code? because I couldn't insert the hyperlink only in the email.