# How can I launch the mail app with flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to open the inbox of the mail app from my app, using flutter.

I found some solutions regarding the `url_launcher` package and setting the `mailto:` value to `''`. However, this didn't work because it opened the compose screen.

Another solution I found was to use the `flutter_appavailability` library, but that is four years old (and was never updated) and I want a package that is new or at least updated constantly.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Check answers here, may help you [open_mail_app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73445337/11217742)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [external_app_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/external_app_launcher)

Otherwise, call the native channel to open a specific app. Details: [Sending the user to another app](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending)