# Flutter WebView Does Not open external links

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, url-launcher

so I´ve been working in a webview project for my php code, the thing is, I have some redirects inside the app, like email, phone and others.

The problema is it doesnt seen to work been trying to use url_launcher, but even with this and a code that seens right, Im stil get the error `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`.

i have seen this topic [Flutter Webview - Opening External Links in Browser or Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65292270/flutter-webview-opening-external-links-in-browser-or-window) but mostly its deprecated, and the new docs doesnt do match for webview

anyway thats the part of my code that is supposed to make it work

```
class MyNavigationDelegate extends NavigationDelegate {
Future\<Object\> shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
WebViewController controller, NavigationRequest navigation) async {
var uri = Uri.parse(navigation.url);

if (uri.scheme == 'mailto') {
final email = uri.path.substring(1);
final mailtoUrl = 'mailto:$email';
await launchUrl(Uri.parse(mailtoUrl));
return NavigationDecision.prevent;
} else if (uri.scheme == 'tel') {`your text`
final tel = uri.path.substring(1);
final telUrl = 'tel:$tel';
await launchUrl(Uri.parse(telUrl));
return NavigationDecision.prevent;
}

return false;`
}

}

class \_MyHomePageState extends State\<MyHomePage\> {
late final WebViewController controller;`

@override`
void initState() {
controller = WebViewController();
controller.setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);
controller.setNavigationDelegate(MyNavigationDelegate());
controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse(" my url "));
addFileSelectionListener();
super.initState();
}\
```

Answer (score 0):

you wrongly formatted code block , re-post the code with right format