# Flutter url_launcher downloading the pdf file instead of opening it in browser

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, url-launcher

I'm using url_launcher: ^5.7.5 and when i'm passing a pdf url in the launch function it it keeps downloading the pdf instead of opening it on my browser,

```
onTap: () async {
    
   url="http://3.65.45.149/uploads/store/vendor_report/vendor_pickup_report_257.pdf";
       if (await canLaunch(url)){
         await launch(url,
         headers: { "Content-Type":"application/pdf",
                     "Content-Disposition":"inline"}, );
            print("browser url");
            print(url);
          }
              else
              // can't launch url, there is some error
              throw "Could not launch $url";
                                                    },
```

Comment: I believe this might help ya https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149055/how-do-i-open-a-web-browser-url-from-my-flutter-code#43889379

Comment: Looks like your browser does not support viewing pdf files. Instead it downloads them.

Comment: it keeps happening in other devices also

Answer (score 2):

In the new version of `URl_laucher` you need to manually specify the launch mode like this:

```dart
return await launchUrl(Uri.parse(command),
        mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication);

for webview mode: Launch.inAppWebView;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated for the newer versions of the `url_launcher` flutter package. The `launch` and `canLaunch` functions are deprecated.**

You can simplify your code and extract it in a compact function:

```
void openPdfFromUrl(String url) {
  debugPrint('opening PDF url = $url');
  var googleDocsUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=${Uri.encodeQueryComponent(url)}';
  debugPrint('opening Google docs with PDF url = $googleDocsUrl');
  final Uri uri = Uri.parse(googleDocsUrl);
  launchUrl(uri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in this case, would be better you be using  [webview_flutter: ^3.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) instead of laucher, hope that helps you!

Comment: so should i use webview instead of url_launcher ?

Comment: I think it can helps you if you're developing for mobile devices, because when you launch the url without the webview, it cannot open the google PDF reader, it is just literally launching the url, but when it open up a webview, it's just like a browser tab, and then  the browser reader could be opened, let me know if it helps you.

Comment: I tried opening it in webview and it returns blank page (for Android). For iOS is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything but what worked for me was instead of launching your file URL directly, attach Google Drive embed link to it

`url = 'https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=${fileUrl}'`

For your case fileUrl = 'http://3.65.45.149/uploads/store/vendor_report/vendor_pickup_report_257.pdf'